# Poll not working in xtemplate

Tags: php

I have the poll option on my real estate website.

I found that poll option is not working.

Here is my Code :

```
<?      
//Fetch Admin Header
$loc = "../includes/";
include($loc.'header.php');
//If POST, process form
if( isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] != ""){           
    $node = new sqlNode();
    $node->table = "`poll_question`";
    $node->push("text","title",$_POST['title']);
    $node->push("html","description",$_POST['description']);
    $node->push("text","date",$_POST['date']);
    $node->where = sprintf("where id = %s", $_POST['id']);
    $redirect = base64_decode($_POST['r']);
    die("<script>window.location='index.php?$redirect';</script>");
    }//End Process Post Form
    $sql = sprintf("select * from `poll_question` where id = %s", $_GET['id']);
    $result = $mysql->exSql($sql) or die($mysql->debugPrint());
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)<1){
    header("Location:index.php");
    die("<script>window.location='index.php'</script>");
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    ?>
```

The value is not getting updated in the database and I don't get any errors.
I can't do step by step process to find out the error as this is the large portal.

Comment: I have updated my post. kindly check it

Comment: Where is your update code ?

Comment: i guess that is the problem. where should i give the update code. Could you help me

Comment: this is too convoluted. tell us by images or examples what your use case is to begin with. when did this stop working, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the Update Code :

```
$result = $mysql->update($node) or die($mysql->debugPrint());
```

So, Here is your Code

```
<?
$loc = "../includes/";
include($loc.'header.php');
//If POST, process form
    if( isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] != ""){           
        $node = new sqlNode();
        $node->table = "`poll_question`";
        $node->push("text","title",$_POST['title']);
        $node->push("html","description",$_POST['description']);
        $node->push("text","date",$_POST['date']);
        $node->where = sprintf("where id = %s", $_POST['id']);
        $result = $mysql->update($node) or die($mysql->debugPrint());
        $redirect = base64_decode($_POST['r']);
        die("<script>window.location='index.php?$redirect';</script>");

    }//End Process Post Form

    $sql = sprintf("select * from `poll_question` where id = %s", $_GET['id']);
    $result = $mysql->exSql($sql) or die($mysql->debugPrint());
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)<1){
        header("Location:index.php");
        die("<script>window.location='index.php'</script>");
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
```